# How to change JSESSIONID in Vaadin after login

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

Im trying to change the JSESSIONID in vaadin after login.

this is my code

```
System.out.println("0000.....OLD-SESSION: " + VaadinSession.getCurrent().getSession().isNew());
System.out.println("0000.....OLD-SESSION-ID: " + VaadinSession.getCurrent().getSession().getId());
VaadinSession.getCurrent().getSession().invalidate();
WrappedSession newSession = VaadinService.getCurrentRequest().getWrappedSession(true);
System.out.println("1111.....NEW-SESSION: " + newSession.isNew());
System.out.println("1111.....NEW-SESSION-ID: " + newSession.getId());
VaadinService.getCurrentResponse().addCookie(new Cookie("JSESSIONID", newSession.getId()));

///////////////////// OUTPUT ////////////////////////
0000.....OLD-SESSION: false
0000.....OLD-SESSION-ID: F353B452D148B35E71920C73EA3BB7AA
1111.....NEW-SESSION: true
1111.....NEW-SESSION-ID: 8C6E4EF40724C060B9B10C1E70FB2441
```

JSESSIONID is changeing successfully but after login on my dashboard im getting SESSION EXPIRED box. How can i resolve this in Vaadin.

*MY AIM: change JSESSION ID after login in VAADIN*

[image]

NOW IM DOING SOMETHING LIKE THIS, im using VaadinService.reinitializeSession

```
System.out.println("0000.....OLD-SESSION: " + VaadinSession.getCurrent().getSession().isNew());
System.out.println("0000.....OLD-SESSION-ID: " + VaadinSession.getCurrent().getSession().getId());
for (Cookie cookie : VaadinService.getCurrentRequest().getCookies())
{
    System.out.println("OLD:: " + cookie.getName() + " - " + cookie.getValue());
}
//                              VaadinSession.getCurrent().getSession().invalidate();
//                              WrappedSession newSession = VaadinService.getCurrentRequest().getWrappedSession(true);

VaadinService.reinitializeSession(VaadinService.getCurrentRequest());
System.out.println("1111.....NEW-SESSION: " + VaadinSession.getCurrent().getSession().isNew());
System.out.println("1111.....NEW-SESSION-ID: " + VaadinSession.getCurrent().getSession().getId());

for (Cookie cookie : VaadinService.getCurrentRequest().getCookies())
{
    System.out.println("NEW:: " + cookie.getName() + " - " + cookie.getValue());
}

VaadinService.getCurrentResponse().addCookie(new Cookie("JSESSIONID", VaadinSession.getCurrent().getSession().getId()));

///////////////// NEW OUTPUT /////////////////
0000.....OLD-SESSION: false
0000.....OLD-SESSION-ID: 7115CC9FF20C2CB485B9F35FDCCF7DEE
OLD:: JSESSIONID - 0D9FCDE46EC8BFDF90A267E01F763EE9
OLD:: JSESSIONID - 7115CC9FF20C2CB485B9F35FDCCF7DEE
1111.....NEW-SESSION: true
1111.....NEW-SESSION-ID: 44969C81DAA007B8CF296C8FCEE6581D
NEW:: JSESSIONID - 0D9FCDE46EC8BFDF90A267E01F763EE9
NEW:: JSESSIONID - 7115CC9FF20C2CB485B9F35FDCCF7DEE
```

but JSESSIONID is not updating on browser cookie

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to change the session ID?

Comment: there is an IS guy from client side :(. who wants me to implement this. I know this thing not affect any kind to session hijacking. who just look into browser resource section and said i need this session id changed on after login and logout too. after logout session id changes successfully.

Comment: Did you ever figured this out? I'm facing something very similar atm: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63035590/how-to-change-jsessionid-after-login-in-vaadin8

Answer (score 2):

Use VaadinService.reinitializeSession

Comment: i have applied your solution but JSESSIONID is not updating on browser :(

Comment: It creates a new server side session. The cookie remains the same

Comment: Strange because http://test.vaadin.com/7.6.4/run/ChangeSessionId?restartApplication seems to work fine and changes the session id. Sources at https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin/blob/master/uitest/src/com/vaadin/tests/applicationcontext/ChangeSessionId.java

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [spring security session fixation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#ns-session-fixation). In my case, the login and the dashboard respectively has own UI. After the login happen a redirect (site reload) to dashboard.

[Spring security](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#ns-session-fixation) generates the new session and migrate necessary data. The new session id is written in the cookie in browser while redirect.